# Progressive matrix with lines going out of circles in the cardinal directions

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

Here's a test that I could not solve.

[image: logic test]

Comment: Where did you see this? Please [edit] the source into your question.

Answer (score 2):

> c. The bottommost picture in each column is the intersection of the above pictures: i.e. any part that appears in *both* the above pictures also appears in the bottom picture.

Comment: I had the same idea...but what about the rows?

Comment: @Someone what about them?

Comment: Shouldn't the rows have a pattern too?

Comment: @Someone idk. I frequently see this type of puzzle answered with reference to only rows or only columns.

Answer (score 1):

> (c) Just superimpose the picture of the first column with the mirror image of second column to get the picture of the third column in the same row.

Comment: mirror image which way?

Comment: I dont understand your question

Comment: @msh210 Mirror image is always the same type no?(sides change)

Comment: which way is the mirror image situated? does it reflect the top half onto the bottom half? the right half onto the left half? diagonally, the top-left half onto the bottom-right half? etc.

Comment: Ohk I understand it now.The mirror is situated in  the right side